# Php curl remote page javascript extraction

Tags: javascript, php, curl

I have a remote page, below shows its source code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>somethingg blabla</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function blala( ) { /*** code **/ }
    var sitedata = {
            "count": 1,
            "threads": {
                "38752": {
                    "thread_id": 38752,
                    "node_id": 4,
                    "title": "The ShadyCraft Beta Launch!", 
                    "prefix_id": 19, 
                    "content": {
                        "count": 1,
                        "content": {
                            "226167": {
                                "post_id": 226167

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
var extra_codes_here = 'blabla';
</script>

<h1>Hello world</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

I have code for curl this page and i got this source code, but how to get the value `var sitedata`  to php array ,

Comment: you want javascript variable in to php array?

Comment: yes i want javascript to php array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$doc; // your document

preg_match('/var\ssitedata\s=\s({.*});/s', $doc, $matches);
$json = $matches[1];
print_r(json_decode($json, true));
```

and your json is incorrect.

```
"post_id": 226167,
```

to

```
"post_id": 226167
```

Comment: this json just copied from internet.. its just a sample.. :)

Comment: copied json is too big then stackoverflow shows too many codes...  just removed some parts ;)